# How to sort a list of lists based on multiplication of elements inside of smaller list

Tags: python, list, multiplication

How do I sort list of lists based on product of multiplication of elements in list?

```
list1 = [[11,11], [15,12], [13,18], [14,21]...[a,b]]
```

How do i sort list from the smallest value of a*b to the highest?
Let's say we have list2 = [[1,1], [5,5], [2,2]],
and i want it to be sorted based of [a,b] inside of a big list so the outcome would be:

```
list3 = [[1,1], [2,2], [5,5]]
```

I kinda tried something like list1.sort[key = a * b] but it does not work and i don't really know how to take up on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unsorted your input list so you can see the result is different:

```
inputs = [[15,12], [13,18], [14,21],[11,11]]

results = sorted(inputs,key=lambda x:x[0]*x[1])

print( f"{results=}" )
```

result:

```
results=[[11, 11], [15, 12], [13, 18], [14, 21]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
list1 = [[11, 11], [15, 12], [13, 18], [14, 21]]

out = sorted(list1, key=lambda k: k[0] * k[1])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[11, 11], [15, 12], [13, 18], [14, 21]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, sort based on the product of elements of nested list

```
def  Sort(sub_li): 
    sub_li.sort(key = lambda x: x[1]*x[0]) 
    return sub_li

sub_li= [[11,11], [15,12], [13,18], [14,21]]
print(Sort(sub_li))
```

Output

```
[[11, 11], [15, 12], [13, 18], [14, 21]]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Welcome happy to hear